# Connection Reset by Peer C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

So I have windows task scheduler that runs my executable every x minutes.

The executable does the following:

1. See if any new messages need to sent to the server using sockets.
2. If there are new messages then make a connection to the server
   and send each message.
3. If there are no new messages then exit the
   executable.

Problem:
My executable does not exit and keeps running.  So the when windows task scheduler runs again it can't execute because an instance of the executable is still running.

The server where I sent the message told me in the error log they see this:

**11-12-19 15:34:09 TCP/IP receive failed; errno 73 - Connection reset by peer.**

My code:

```
namespace TransportMessage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var systemUserId = 1

            try
            {
                using (var dbContext = new DBContext())
                {
                    var unsentRecords = dbContext.Records.Where(x => x.status == "QUEUED").ToList();

                    if (unsentRecords != null && unsentRecords.Count > 0)
                    {
                        var portNumber = 45454;
                        var dnsName = "xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";

                        IPAddress[] ipAddresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(dnsName);

                        Socket soc = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                        IPAddress ipAdd = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(ipAddresses[0].ToString());
                        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAdd, portNumber);
                        soc.Connect(remoteEP);

                        foreach (var rec in unsentRecords)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rec.message_text);
                                var numberOfBytesSent = soc.Send(byData);

                                byte[] buffer = new byte[8000];
                                int iRx = soc.Receive(buffer);
                                char[] chars = new char[iRx];

                                Decoder d = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
                                int charLen = d.GetChars(buffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
                                string recv = new string(chars);

                                rec.sent_ack_message = recv;
                                rec.number_of_bytes_sent = numberOfBytesSent;

                                var ackMessageStatus = rec.AckMessageStatus();

                                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ackMessageStatus))
                                {
                                    if (ackMessageStatus == "NNN")
                                    {
                                        //Sent successfully.  NNN= Good
                                        rec.status = Status.SENT.ToString();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        //User received anything else which means something bad in the message.
                                        rec.status = Status.FAILED.ToString();
                                        rec.last_failed_date = DateTime.Now;
                                        rec.last_failed_reason = "Message format incorrect. Please contact IT Operations. Ack Message status " + ackMessageStatus + ".";
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    rec.status = Status.QUEUED.ToString();
                                    rec.last_failed_date = DateTime.Now;
                                    rec.last_failed_reason = "Message sent but no acknowledgment message was received. Message sent back to queued state to try again.";
                                }

                                rec.last_modified_by = systemUserId;
                                rec.last_modified_date = DateTime.Now;
                                rec.status_date = DateTime.Now;
                                rec.sent_date = DateTime.Now;
                                rec.sent_attempt_count = rec.sent_attempt_count + 1;
                                dbContext.SaveChanges();

                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                rec.status = Status.FAILED.ToString();
                                rec.last_modified_by = systemUserId;
                                rec.last_modified_date = DateTime.Now;
                                rec.status_date = DateTime.Now;
                                rec.last_failed_date = DateTime.Now;
                                rec.last_failed_reason = e.ToString();
                                rec.sent_attempt_count = rec.sent_attempt_count + 1;
                                dbContext.SaveChanges();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException e)
            {
                Util.LogError(LogType.FAILED_CONNECTION, e.Message, e.StackTrace);
            }
            catch (System.Data.DataException e)
            {
                Util.LogError(LogType.FAILED_TO_CONNECT_TO_DATABASE, e.Message, e.StackTrace);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //General error if its not database or a socket exception issue.
                Util.LogError(LogType.ERROR, e.Message, e.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Question:
How do I handle when I get a connection reset by the peer?

I was thinking maybe after I call soc.Connect(remoteEP).  I check to see if soc.Connected is false.  If so then I disconnect.

```
  if (!soc.Connected)
  {
    soc.Disconnect(true);
  }
```

Note:
I was disconnecting the socket after I sent my messages but the admin working on the server told me not to do that.  Also the executable has been running fine for 3 weeks.  No errors or anything.

Comment: From cmd.exe try : Netstat -a which will give state of connection.  You are not closing the connection so it is staying open and then preventing a another connection from being established.  A connection has 3 properties 1) IP Source Address 2) IP Destination Address 3) Port number.  You cannot have two connections where all three properties are identical.  Netstat -a will show that you have a connection that isn't closing.

Comment: I just ran netstat -a on the server and I don't see it.  I think the question is why would my app above not close.  What is causing it to hang?

Comment: Do you see port 45454 in Netstat when the application is running?  TCP connection can close in what is called a half open/half close state.  So even if the server is not showing the connection, the client can still be open.  When a TCP connection closes there are ACKs that occur.  So when an ACK is not returned the connection starts to close but never finishes. This often happens if both the client and server attempt to close a connection at the same time and a race condition occurs.  To prevent this, you should always close a TCP connection from client and never from server.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation of how it works. I will have to run netstat tomorrow when there are messages in the queue.  Right now there are no messages.  I would assume its there.  I was closing the connection after I sent my messages but then the admin who works with the server told me to not disconnect.

Comment: The admin also told me this "Q: What is the meaning of the "connection reset by peer" error on a TCP connection? Is it a fatal error or just a notification or related to the network failure?

A: It's fatal. The remote server has sent you a RST packet, which indicates an immediate dropping of the connection, rather than the usual handshake. This bypasses the normal half-closed state transition."

Comment: So the solution you suggesting is to disconnect after I send all my messages?

Comment: The connection needs to be closed before opening a second time.  Not sure why the connection did not close.  Using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler will help locate issue.  You admin reference to the RESET bit in the TCP header is interesting.  It doesn't tell why the server actually sent the message.  The root cause could be in the client code.  The server could of received a packet with a bad CRC or may think you connection is a service attack due to routing loops, bad credentials (if TLS is being used), or maybe bad hardware.  To test for errors use from cmd.exe : Ping IP -t -l 65500

Comment: I'm already in production.  I will need to test the closing of the connection code in another environment.  You said "You admin reference to the RESET bit in the TCP header is interesting." What is the RESET bit?

Comment: See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol